# Why can't we use expression-bodied constructors?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, visual-studio-2015

Using the new Expression-Bodied Members feature in C# 6.0, we can take a method like this:

```
public void Open()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Opened");
}
```

...and change it to a simple expression with equivalent functionality:

```
public void Open() => Console.WriteLine("Opened");
```

This is not true for constructors, however. Code such as this doesn't compile:

```
private DbManager() => Console.WriteLine("ctor");
```

Nor does this:

```
private DbManager() => {}
```

Is there any reason why constructors cannot benefit from the expression-bodied members feature, and must be declared the traditional way?

Comment: I can only provide a *guess* here... basically they're considerably less useful for constructors, and the main use case for expression-bodied members is where they *return* something, whereas in a constructor you're not returning anything. Note that your final example is more longwinded than just writing the code *without* the `=>`.

Comment: There were some experiments around constructors that were abandoned for C# 6.0. There are some more features planed for C# 7.0 involving constructors and there was a decision to not change anything regarding constructors this time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Opponents of expression-bodied constructors posited it would be more confusing than useful. Especially when you add a call to another constructor.

Here's the direct quote from the design notes:

> Constructors have syntactic elements in the header in the form of this(…) or base(…) initializers which would look strange just before a fat arrow. More importantly, constructors are almost always side-effecting statements, and don’t return a value.

From [C# Design Notes for Nov 4, 2013](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540574)

In a more general way:

> To summarize, expression bodies are allowed on methods and user defined operators (including conversions), where they express the value returned from the function, and on properties and indexers where they express the value returned from the getter, and imply the absence of a setter.

Answer (score 7):

Now that the c# 7.0 has been released it is possible to use expression-bodied constructors.

```
private DbManager() => Console.WriteLine("ctor");
```

works fine in c# 7.0

Comment: @Gigi They were never technical challenges. The argument was they "would look strange just before a fat arrow".

Comment: Not working using 2 properties: `List1 = new List<string>(); List2= new List<string>();`

Comment: @Kiquenet You can use tuple patterns to emulate what you want: `public Lists() => (List1, List2) = (new List<string>(), new List<string>())`